# Text spacing between the line in the react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text, react-hooks

There are two text placed in column manner. Both of the text has numberoflines set to 1. When the text fits exactly in the one line then there is higher spacing betweeen these two text as compared to when the text overflows in the one line. I am attaching a screenshot of this. Please help me out why this is occuring and how can i solve this issue.

[image]

[image]

Test name 0 and test tagline 0 spacing in image 1 is more as compared to Test name 0abcd... And test tagline 0 abcdg...in image 2

```
  nameText: {
    // fontSize: fontDimens.medium,
    // lineHeight: 20,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: colors.black,
    fontSize: widthToDp(fontDimensPer.large),
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-SemiBold',
    // paddingBottom: 1
    // flexShrink: 1
  },
  tagLine: {
    // fontSize: fontDimens.extraSmall,
    // lineHeight: 16,
    fontWeight: '400',
    // paddingBottom: 2,
    color: colors.black,
    // paddingVertical: 2,
    fontSize: widthToDp(fontDimensPer.medium),
    // lineHeight: 16,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-SemiBold',
    // flexShrink: 1
  },

  <View>
            <CustomText textStyle={styles.nameText} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>{capitalizeFirstLetterOnly(name)}</CustomText>
            <CustomText textStyle={styles.tagLine} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>{capitalizeFirstLetterOnly(tagline)}</CustomText>
          </View>
```

the issue is because of custom font if i remove the custom font then there is no issue

Comment: how are you styling the text components? Can you put a code snippet?

Comment: ```  nameText: {
    // fontSize: fontDimens.medium,
    // lineHeight: 20,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: colors.black,
    fontSize: widthToDp(fontDimensPer.large),
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-SemiBold',
    // paddingBottom: 1
    // flexShrink: 1
  },
  tagLine: {
    // fontSize: fontDimens.extraSmall,
    // lineHeight: 16,
    fontWeight: '400',
    // paddingBottom: 2,
    color: colors.black,
    // paddingVertical: 2,
    fontSize: widthToDp(fontDimensPer.medium),
    // lineHeight: 16,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-SemiBold',
    // flexShrink: 1
  },